# createUser is not a function, when trying handleSubmit as async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-context

I am trying to practice user Authentication, login and signup, and most of it have had no issue, unfortunately when i am trying to signup it says that createUser is not a function.
**SignUp Component** is as followed + **marked the line of error as** ==> :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { UserAuth } from '../context/AuthContext'

const Signup = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [error, setError] = useState('')

    const { createUser } = UserAuth()

  ** ==>  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            setError('')
            try {
                await createUser(email, password);
            } catch (e) {
                setError(e.message)
                console.log(e.message)
            }
    }** <==

  return (
    <div className='max-w-[700px] mx-auto my-16 p-4'>
    
        <div>
            <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold py-2'>Sign Up for free!</h1>
            <p>Already have an account? <Link to='/' className='underline'>Sign In</Link></p>
            </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className='flex flex-col py-2'>
                <label className='py-2 font-medium'>Email Address</label>
                <input onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value) } className='border p-3' type='email' />
            </div>
            <div className='flex flex-col py-2'>
            <label className='py-2 font-medium'>Password</label>
            <input onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} className='border p-3' type='password' />
        </div>
            <button className='border border-blue-500 bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-500 w-full p-4 my-2 text-white'>Sign Up</button>
        
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Signup
```

The **AuthContext** file from where i am importing createUser is as followed:

```
import {createContext, useContext } from "react";
import {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut,
    onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from "../firebase";




const UserContext = createContext()

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) => {

    const createUser = (email, password) => {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={createUser}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const UserAuth = () => {
    return useContext(UserContext)
}
```

please help me out to find error so i can learn <3

Answer (score 3):

Either do this:

```
<UserContext.Provider value={{createUser}}>
```

or this:

```
const createUser = UserAuth()
```

Because you exported a simple value not an object

Comment: thank you,it gets messed up sometimes. means alot <3 @Konrad Linkowski